# Почему Qt 5.12.12 не принимает "ndk;21.3.6528147" cmdline-tools;latest", когда те установлены?

Tags: c++, qt5, android-sdk

1. 

> ```
> "Изменения в Android SDK - Qt Creator"
> Qt Creator couldn't find the following essential package "ndk;21.3.6528147" cmdline-tools;latest".
> Install them manually after the current operation is done.
> ```

2. Выполняется методом скачивания пакета, проверки `source.properties`, версия совпадает. Qt принимает пакет как NDK, но считает зависимость не удовлетворённой.
3. Сейчас cmdline-tools latest это 8.0. Пробовал также 2-е, не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

NDK r19 is required, соответственно нужно не latest ставить, а https://wiki.qt.io/Android сюда зайти. Вы ставили r21.

Comment: Там между 5.12.0 - 5.12.5 r19c;
А 5.12.6+ r21

Comment: В случае всяком. Проект создался. Следувющая проблема, не удаётся подключиться к jkcenter.com. Forbidden 403 (~регион заблокирован). Нужно поменять адрес репозитория "Gradle Cache". Получается н Androide программирование Ресетовское для регионов которых еще не отключили.